# Issue with GitHub Pages and Blazor

Tags: blazor, github-pages

I have two GitHub repositories, both built using Blazor and GitHub pages. The first is https://github.com/xlq902/blazortest, and it works...however, the other one, https://github.com/nlrpg/nlrpg.github.io, is under an organization account. I even first built it under my xlq902 account, when it worked, then transferred ownership to nlrpg.

When I visit the address https://nlrpg.github.io, the following error always occurs:

[image: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in blazor.webassembly.js:1]

Does anyone know why this occurs? Help would very much be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Only point I could find was in index.html, at line 22: `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, but that is the entire dotnet framework. Dig deeper. Do you know how to use the browser Dev Tools (F12) ?

Comment: Not really, no 

but I'll see if I can figure it out from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/javascript/#:~:text=Get%20started%20with%20debugging%20JavaScript%20in%20Microsoft%20Edge,variable%20values.%20...%207%20Apply%20a%20fix.%20

My only question is what am I looking for? Under "Event Listener Breakpoints" I've checked "load" and "error"...

Comment: Go to the Network tab, then F5. Look for a JSon file, check the URL (compare with a working version).  You can check a URL with the browser.

Comment: I think is incorrect the base tag must be <base href="/" />

Comment: I don't see any network calls being made.  @Santiago, did you compile this in release mode?  If so, you may want to try switching to Debug mode until after you diagnose the problem.

Comment: The failing request is https://nlrpg.github.io/nlrpg.github.io/_framework/blazor.boot.json . as @Santiago says, your `base` tag is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to remove this 3 lines from you GitHub Action workflow to keep the base tag untouched

[image]